# Get combinations with condition Scala|Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, combinations, cartesian

I have an RDD tagIDs with the following content:

> (name_1, Set_1), 
>   ...
>   (name_t, Set_t),
>   ...

I want to create pairs of pairs (name_i, Set_i), (name_j, Set_j), but only if `Set_i.intersect(Set_j).size > 0`

The only way I managed to do that is:

```
  val withInd = tagIds.zipWithIndex()
  val tagIdsZipped = withInd.cartesian(withInd)
    .filter{
        case(a, b) => (a._2 < b._2 && a._1._2.intersect(b._1._2).size>0)
    }
    .map{
        case(a, b) => (a._1, b._1)
    }
```

I wonder if there are any more efficient ways for that, because, I think, cartesian produce too much of pairs which will be removed in filter, and I want to avoid it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to look at each pair to know if there's a non-empty intersection of the sets. So you have to look at all the pairs anyway => cartesian

Comment: well, that makes sense, thank you